# redirect from http to https and back to http within java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, https

there are a bunch of links accessing my servlet without https
As the servlet is a generic form and the http urls are generated with an random id it is difficult to use modrewrite or something like that.

Therefore I modified my servlet with code like that:

```
//redirect to https
        String sec = servletRequest.getParameter("Sec");
        String qString = servletRequest.getQueryString();

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(sec)){
              try {
                    HttpServletResponse rsp = request.getServletResponse(true);


                         String PORTAL_URL = l_aliasHelper.getPath(request);


              rsp.sendRedirect("https://"+servletRequest.getServerName() +PORTAL_URL+"?" +qString+"&Sec=yes");
              } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              }

        }
```

Now this works fine!

But, what if I want back to http because I want to avoid nagging warnings about insecure elements on other pages.

**So how do I redirect to http again after the user has submitted the form?**

If everything worked well the user gets displayed a response with a success message under the same URL he started.

```
So the cycle goes like this: 
http://<somedomain>/<anypath>?<anyid>
https://<somedomain>/<anypath>?<anyid>&Sec=yes
and now it should go back maybe with a step inbetween to
http://<somedomain>/<anypath>?<anyid> <- the success message should be
displayed here
```

the last method before the message is displayed is
sucessmessage.render(request,response)

request and response are both appserver component specific views on all request / response related matters. They have methods like:

> getServletResponse
>
> public HttpServletResponse getServletResponse(boolean answering)
>
> ```
> Gets the original servlet response. Note: This should be accessed
> ```
>
> in extraordinary cases only. If the parameter is set to true all
>   further content procession of the runtime will be skipped. This is
>   only available, if the request was initiated from a servlet based
>   connection.

**So how can the response be manipulated in a way that the form is submitted secure, but the user can go on with http on the rest of the site afterwards.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to do too much in one place. Maybe the following break down will be easier:

- Specify https in the URL for the action parameter in HTML form.
- Create a ServletFilter class that uses `ServletRequest.isSecure()` to
  make sure that requests to your form action actually came in over
  https. This could also be in your action servlet, but making it a filter means you can reuse it. Just make sure the secure servlets have this filter set.
- In your form action servlet, simply send a redirect to the
  success page over http

Comment: I decided to just send the submit over https and redirect the user back to http aterwards. If a user want to see what he has sent an https link with a popup window is shown. That way I dont have problems with beeing stuck in https and the content is submitted secure.